# creating postfix email user without shell access

Tags: server, permissions, postfix, mail

I have currently setup Postfix mail server for my company, but there is a bit of problem, the users I have defined for mail server MUST have shell access to server otherwise Postfix won't recognise it when he/she is trying to login which could not be true; I don't want my employees to have shell access to the server.

### Questions:

1. How can I define a mail user without giving it a permission to access server's shell?
2. Is there any web-GUI for this kind of stuff(manage mail servers users) that I am not aware of?

---

PS. I am currently using postfix 2.11.0 and ubuntu server 14.04LTS

Answer (score 1):

I can't test it at the moment however, I believe nologin will work for you.

```
sudo usermod -s /usr/sbin/nologin username
```

It will only affect the users shell access, by instead of setting a default shell it will politely tell them to go away.

Additionally, postfix.admin may be the tool you're looking for to manage your users with a web interface.

http://postfixadmin.sourceforge.net/